# Backquote on SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, regex

I want to send a `for` though SSH, but with backquotes

Example :

```bsh
ssh $user@$computer "for i in `$command` do; echo $i; done"
```

Problem, it didn't work as expected. If i do

```bsh
\`$command\`
```

The command is escaped in the remote computer, and if i didn't, it's interpreted by the local computer

I tried too with EOF but no more success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The former is normal. Backticks, just like `$variables` and `$(commands)`, are always interpreted within double-quoted strings. It's not an SSH thing; your local shell applies the same syntax rules no matter what command you run.

If in doubt, first try with `echo`, and you'll see the exact string that'll get sent to the remote server:

```
$ command="id"
$ echo "for i in \`$command\`; do echo \$i; done"
for i in `id`; do echo $i; done
```

Try with a shell (Bash here, but ideally the same shell as the remote server runs):

```
$ command="id"
$ bash -c "for i in \`$command\`; do echo \$i; done"
uid=1000(grawity)
gid=100(users)
groups=100(users)
```

Now it's practically guaranteed to work with SSH as well:

```
$ command="id"
$ ssh root@somehost "for i in \`$command\`; do echo \$i; done"
uid=0(root)
gid=0(root)
groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon)
```

(It may be easier to replace `` `$command` `` with `$($command)`, then only the outer $ needs to be escaped.)

Comment: For me, with `$($command)` it execute the command locally, and with `\$($command)` it says "bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `do'"

Comment: That's because the `;` goes before `do`, not after.

Comment: Thanks, that's all good !